# Database scheme design query

Tags: mysql, database-design

i am designing a database which will be used for a website used to exchange automobiles.

Autos have different attributes and types of attibutes like

Attributes of Type "Multimedia", "Security" etc
for examlpe ABS, Airbages, ESP ect

I want to save all these attributes in one cloumn in the form of 1 and 0 combinitation

like

1001000101

but my problem is if I change the position of attribute names in database how this combination "1001000101" will be updated? or which should be the best possible way to do this.

Comment: Is MySQL a requirement? I think, modern NoSQL databases could help here. MongoDB, for example.

Comment: Why not use multiple columns? Is there a reason it must be done this particular way?

Comment: @Martin Woe on those modelling attributes into columns! Changing your data model for every single attribute that will be added in the future is even worse than denormalizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What benefit do you expect to gain from putting all the flags into a single column, that would outweigh the maintainability of having them as separate boolean properties?

Provided your set of flags is reasonably stable, I'd recommend you at least *start* by modelling them as individual boolean columns, which will be much simpler to manage. Make managing them more complicated later if it will provide some other measurable benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [bit data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) (see [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) - seem a more logical and simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way and save the attributes in one data field, changing the relation "attribute" to the position has to result into an adminstrative update of the data. Since the database doesn't know the relation, there's no easy way to automate this updates.

Each time such an event occurs, you have to do something like this.

Theory based on this kind of table:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `yourfield` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `backupfield` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

1. Store the old value on a separate field.

This might look like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET backupfield = yourfield;
```

1. Update the field.

If you swap Position 3 with 7, it may look something like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = CONCAT(
    LEFT(backupfield,2),    // everything left of first position
    MID(backupfield,7,1),   // old position 7
    MID(backupfield,4,3),   // everything between first and 2nd position 
    MID(backupfield,3,1),   // old position 3
    MID(backupfield,8));    // everything right of 2nd position
```

Is there any reason you want to do it this way? If there's no specific reason for it, either use separate fields (way easier).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't have to deal with serious performance issues, you should not de-normalize your database.

Some years back I worked on a major used car marketplace and we added a text column containing the delimited id values of the cars equipment items `,1,3,7,55,` and used `equiment LIKE '%,55,%' in our search queries.

However we always kept our normalized data model with a relation between car and equipment

```
car_id    equip_id
1         3
1         55
```

Keeping the `equipment` column and the `car_equipment` relation in sync can either be handled by your DAL or by database triggers.

Always keep in mind that aside from serving your frontend marketplace you may have to provide reporting for other purposes - if all your equipment/attribute data is encoded in one column that can't queried without logic built your DAL, you're busted.